# How to show this is convex? $\frac{(x_1-x_2+x_3+1)^2}{x_1+x_2}$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

$$\sqrt{2x_1^2+x_1x_2+4x_2^2+4}+\frac{(x_1-x_2+x_3+1)^2}{x_1+x_2}\leq6$$

I think the square root part can be written as follows:

$$||(\frac12(x_1+x_2)^2,\frac{\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}x_1,\frac{\sqrt7}{\sqrt2}x_2,2)^T||$$

where ||.|| is Euclidian norm. It is a composition of a 2-norm with an affine transformation and therefore is convex.

But stuck on the second expression. I know it can be found by Hessian, but for more complicated functions it can be very costly in terms of time and it requires a lot of attention if you solve it by hand. I wanted to ask if there is relatively shorter way to do that as I have mentioned for the square root expression.

How do you think I can show it is convex?

**Edit:** Also looking for this one:

$$\frac{(x_1^2+x_2^2)^2}{(x_1+x_2)^2}$$

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the Hessian Matrix ? If the Hessian Matrix is positive definite then you have your answer

Comment: Yes I know, but for more complicated functions it can be very costly in terms of time and it requires a lot of attention if you solve it by hand. I wanted to ask if there is relatively shorter way to do that as I have mentioned for the square root expression.

Comment: Searching for the phrase “quadratic-over-linear function” may help here